# Create multiple users in APEX test coverage

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, change-set, user

I have been trying to transport my change set from the developer sandbox to production and I'm getting an error when I try to do this.

The error:

> ***Failure Message: "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_USERNAME, Duplicate Username.
> Another user has already selected this username.
> Please select another.: [Username]"***

This error only shows up went trying to upload a change set from the sandboxes to production, but not from one sandbox to another sandbox. This is misleading a bit.

The idea is to create several users to test Event with EvenRelations. All the code has being tested 100% on the sandbox. The APEX trigger, in this case, works fine and like I said it has being test with a 100% coverage result. This a small part of the code that creates the users:

```
`Profile p = [select id FROM Profile WHERE Name ='ProfileNmae'];

User user1 = new User();
user1.Username = 'us1@test.com';
user1.Email = 'us1@test.com';
user1.LastName = 'LastName1';
user1.FirstName = 'FirstName1';
user1.Alias ='u1';
user1.CommunityNickname ='use1';
user1.ProfileId =p.id;

user1.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8';
user1.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US';
user1.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
user1.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
user1.Country = 'US';
user1.Title = 'Territory Manager';


insert user1;
userId.add(user1.id);


EventRelation eventRelationUser1 = new EventRelation();

eventRelationUser1.RelationId = user1.id;
eventRelationUser1.Status = 'Accepted';
eventRelationUser1.EventId = eventTestId;

insert eventRelationUser1;

system.assertEquals('Accepted', eventRelationUser1.Status);
system.assertEquals(eventRelationUser1.EventId, eventTestId);

User user2 = new User();
user2.Username = 'us2@test.com';
user2.Email = 'us2@test.com';
user2.LastName = 'LastName';
user2.FirstName = 'FirstName2';
user2.Alias ='u2';
user2.CommunityNickname ='use2';
user2.ProfileId =p.id;

user2.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8';
user2.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US';
user2.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
user2.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
user2.Country = 'US';
user2.Title = 'Field Service Manager';
```

`

So this is the approach I used on the test code and it works, but that is not the case when moving the change set to production. 
I have been reading and I have been trying to get a solution for this. I found out that you need to have unique users when using test codes in production, fine. 
So I found this code that it will create a unique user from your code when moving test APEX codes to production:

```
public static User createTestUser(Id roleId, Id profID, String fName, String lName) {
    String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
    String dateString = String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','');
    Integer randomInt = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000));
    String uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;
    User tuser = new User(  firstname = fName,
                            lastName = lName,
                            email = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org',
                            Username = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org',
                            EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
                            Alias = uniqueName.substring(18, 23),
                            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                            ProfileId = profId,
                            UserRoleId = roleId);
    return tuser;
}
```

After trying this it looks like the first test users is not showing up as a duplicate USERNAME anymore but the second one those. Anyone knows how I can use this or any other code to make sure that the test users I have in my test code are unique, and allow me to upload the change set to production?

regards,

V

Comment: So let me get this straight, you are having issues with generating unique usernames?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. I need to generate unique usenames to move my test code to production.

Comment: incidentally... promoting from sandbox to sandbox does not runAllTests, which is why you can do that and not to a production environment...

Comment: cant you just use usernames as us1@test.com.unitTest01, us1@test.com.unitTest02 ..?

Comment: If I do that in developer or full sandbox, no problem. In a matter of fact that is what I use. The problem is that this is a "no go" went moving the code to production. If I do that with this approach you mentioned, the error stop me from fully upload the change set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this error:

***Failure Message: "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_USERNAME, Duplicate Username.
Another user has already selected this username.
Please select another.: [Username]"***

By creating this:

```
`String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
 String dateString = String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace('   ','').replace(':','').replace('-','');
 Integer randomInt = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000));
 String uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;`
```

And then I use this combination to obtain a unique username.

```
`Profile p = [select id FROM Profile WHERE Name ='Administrator'];

 User user1 = new User();
 user1.Username = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org';
 user1.Email = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org';
 user1.LastName = 'LastName1';
 user1.FirstName = 'FirstName1';
 user1.Alias = uniqueName.substring(18, 23);
 user1.CommunityNickname ='use1';
 user1.ProfileId =p.id;

 user1.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8';
 user1.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US';
 user1.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
 user1.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
 user1.Country = 'US';
 user1.Title = 'Territory Manager';


insert user1;`
```

If I try to transfer my change set now I have no problems with the username.
I repeat this for the second user but I created a second set of **Integer radomInt** and **String uniqueName**.

`Integer randomInt2 = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*2000000));`

I notice that if I use the same randomInt for my second username the random composition of 
`String uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;` will be the same than the one for the first user and it's not unique.

But using `String uniqueName2 = orgId + dateString + randomInt2;` for the second user will works, creating a new username that is unique.

This is a solution. Any comments on this?

**Edit 11-21-14**

So far there is not problems and the code has been active for a few months. We are going to modify all test classes and add a test factory class to avoid issues like this one.

Comment: My apologies, I was not giving the correct error msg, I just realized that :( .. I have change the posts to the right error msg: Failure Message:** "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_USERNAME, Duplicate Username.<br>Another user has already selected this username.<br>Please select another.: [Username]"**

Comment: I usually create Users (and all Test data) from a TestUtility Class. There I define a static variable countUsersCreated (which is increased with each created user) and I append this to the username string. Question: I am quite sure that the CommunityNickname must be unique accross your org. Doesn't it fail your insert ?

Comment: It is not good practice to create users using DML in a test class, ie "insert user1". Use System.runAs(user1){} instead. Also, see known issue with regards to username being unique across all sandboxes: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XDOAA2